# Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update(), 0 passed

Tags: laravel

I am getting the following error when I update my model:

**Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update(), 0 passed**

Here is my code:

```
$clientBank  = ClientBank::where('company_profile_id',$this->param('company_profile_id'));
        if($clientBank->count()){
            $clientBankId = $clientBank->first()->id;
            $cientBank = ClientBank::find($clientBankId);
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if($key !='mobile_banks')
                 $clientBank->$key = $value;
            }
            $clientBank->updated_at       = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    
            $clientBank->update();
        }else{
            $clientBank = new ClientBank;
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                 $clientBank->$key = $value;
            }
            $clientBank->company_profile_id = $this->param('company_profile_id');
            $clientBank->updated_at       = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
            $clientBank->save();
    
        }
```

Where $data has the following post data:

```
Array
(
    [account_name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
    [account_number] => 0164545215454
    [bank_name] => DBBL
    [mobile_banks] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => bKash
                    [accout_number] => 01564545644
                    [account_type] => 1
                )
        )  
)
```

Model definition:

```
class ClientBank extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'client_banks';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    protected $casts = [
     "mobile_banks" => "array"
    ];
}
```

What's problem in my code or approach? Any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. You want `->save()`. The `update()` method exists to update specific properties/columns, see also the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent.

Comment: Okay. thanks for your suggestion. I will try to follow this next time.

Answer (score 1):

[update](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_update) method meant to take an array of key values as columns and values to update your table according to that array,

in your case just use `save` method:

```
$clientBank->save();
```

Comment: but I want to update if any data found matching with company_profile_id

Comment: got this error: Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::save()

Comment: please try change $cientBank = ClientBank::find($clientBankId); to $cientBank = ClientBank::firstWhere('id',$clientBankId);